# I am trying to open/run a model that was created in AnyLogic 7 in the AnyLogic 8 software and I am unable to open the model

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to open and run a model that was created in AnyLogic 7 in AnyLogic 8 (8.8.6, specifically), but I get the following error:[error message for opening model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKONC.png). Please advise. This model was created by my advisor and published on github with access via the Data Availability Statement in McEwan et al 2015_PLoS One. The source code of the AnyLogic model can be downloaded from https://github.com/gmcewan/SalmonFarmRefugia.

Comment: The advise is literally in the error message, no? You can also ask support@anylogic.com for the version needed, if you don't have the "Support" button (PLE version)

Comment: Thank you! I used the 'support' button and it brought me to stack overflow. I will try to contact via your suggestion.